# Scraping a Website without Crawling the "Search Engine" section of the page

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Lately I've been trying to develop a Web Crawler using Scrapy to extract all the PDF documents from a specific domain and, although I can somehow achieve the goal, it still gets stuck in some kind of an "infinite loop" because of the "search engine" part of the said website.

Is there any way that I can avoid this kind of behavior?

Here's the code of the crawler that has been written so far (sorry if it's spaghetti, still trying to get better..):

```
class AirbusSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "test"
    tag = "aircraft"
    n_iterations = 3
    allowed_domains = ['airbus.com']

    start_urls = [
        'https://www.airbus.com'
    ]

def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

def parse(self, response):
    yield scrapy.Request(url=response.url+'/'+self.tag+'.html', callback=self.parse_item, meta={'iteration': self.n_iterations})


def parse_item(self, response):
    current_iteration = response.meta['iteration']
    if(current_iteration>0):

        temp_links = []
        valuable_links = []
        current_iteration-=1

        #all "somewhat-valuable" links to crawl into
        links = response.selector.xpath('//a[contains(@href,"aircraft")]/@href').extract() #all hrefs of current page

        for link in links:
            valuable_links.append(link)

        temp_links = set(valuable_links) 
        valuable_links = list(temp_links)

        for link in valuable_links:
            link = str(link.encode('utf-8'))
            if '.pdf' not in link:
                if(link[0] == '/' or link[0] == '#'):
                    yield scrapy.Request(url=self.start_urls[0]+link, callback=self.parse_item, meta={'iteration': current_iteration})
                else:
                    yield scrapy.Request(url=link, callback=self.parse_item, meta={'iteration': current_iteration})
            else:
                if(link[0] == '/'  or link[0] == '#'):
                    #increase the priority of these requests
                    yield scrapy.Request(url=self.start_urls[0]+link, callback=self.download_file, priority = 1)
                else:
                    yield scrapy.Request(url=link, callback=self.download_file, priority = 1)

def download_file(self, response):
    item = PdfLink()
    item['link'] = str(response.url)

    return item
```

I tried to limit the recursion by adding a cap (n_iterations) of how deeply the crawler should dig into. It works but still, I'd like to filter the links it crawls into in a proper manner.

Thank you so much for helping me out, have a good week!